# How to ensure logic applies to last item in file during loop?

Tags: bash, loops

I currently have a loop that is gpg verifying some files, keeping track of some urls that they are corresponding to.

I want to be able to write the "good" urls to a file when the gpg verification passes.

It is working great, except for one url in `$URL_LIST` that is showing up in the `trusted_tars.txt` file that does not belong. It also happens to be the **very last url listed in** `$URL_LIST` so I think that there is some logic I need in my loop that isn't there.

Here is my code now:

```
while IFS= read -r url <&3 && read -r line <&4; 
do 
   if gpg --verify $line; 
   then  
     echo $url >> trusted_tars.txt; 
   else
     echo "$url failed gpg check at $line";
   fi
done 3<"$URL_LIST" 4<gpg_verify.txt
```

I have also tried:

```
while IFS= read -r url || [ -n "$url" ] <&3 && read -r line || [ -n "$line" ] <&4; 
do 
   if gpg --verify $line; then  
   echo $url >> trusted_tars.txt; else
   echo "$url failed gpg check at $line";
   fi
done 3<"$URL_LIST" 4<gpg_verify.txt
```

but that just makes my script hang... Maybe I am on the right track with this, but just sequencing things wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are missing a linefeed on the last line of one of the files. Try appending one to each before you enter the loop, e.g. `echo >> gpg_verify.txt`

Comment: Consider surrounding `$line` with double quotes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have tried your suggestion but still have the same result.

Comment: Did you append onto $URL_LIST too?

Comment: Yes, I did `echo >> gpg_verify.txt` `echo >> $URL_LIST` with same result

Comment: Why have you got semicolons everywhere?

Comment: `+ IFS=
+ read -r url
+ read -r line
+ gpg --verify signatures/zookeeper-3.5.6.sig manifests/zookeeper-3.5.6.json
gpg: Signature made Wed Jan 29 00:46:08 2020 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key A4466BA2251482B8
gpg: Good signature from "Private (DCAR Signing Key) <dccscr-leadership@private.com>" [ultimate]
+ set -x
+ echo https://private/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/sonatype/nexus/nexus/3.16.2-01/2019-11-18T152622.427_1790/nexus-3.16.2-01.tar
+ IFS=
+ read -r url`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208148/discussion-between-swarren-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: Provide a [mcve], its more difficult to help without a test we can try.